# Android crash on button.setEnabled(false)

Tags: java, android, xml, crash

**Ok so I finally figured out the source of my problem. After a bunch of tests and trying out different things I noticed that after I put the codes**

```
button1.setEnabled(false);
button2.setEnabled(false);
button3.setEnabled(false);
button4.setEnabled(false);
```

**in onCreateView, it would crash upon startup. This is in my menu1_Fragment.java and is my first fragment. In my class I start off by defining my buttons.**

```
Button button1;
Button button2;
Button button3;
Button button4;
```

**Then the first thing I do in onCreateView is run the function setButton();**

```
    public void setButton() {
            button1 = (Button) rootview.findViewById(R.id.upgbutton);
            button2 = (Button) rootview.findViewById(R.id.upgbutton1);
            button3 = (Button) rootview.findViewById(R.id.upgbutton2);
            button4 = (Button) rootview.findViewById(R.id.upgbutton3);
        }
```

**What happens here is that these buttons are actually in my menu2_layout.xml which is my second fragment but my rootview allows me to find it. Then after I defined my buttons right below I set all my buttons to false as seen in the first bit of code because I don't want the user to be clicking the buttons yet. This is where I found that it crashes upon start. Here is the code for my buttons.**

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="4">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_state2_xml"
            android:id="@+id/upgbutton"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_state3_xml"
            android:id="@+id/upgbutton1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_state4_xml"
            android:id="@+id/upgbutton2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_state5_xml"
            android:id="@+id/upgbutton3"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />


            </LinearLayout>
```

**I gave all my buttons their own selector_state because that is what initially I thought the problem was. Here is the code for my selector.**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/buttonclick" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/buttongray" android:state_enabled="false"></item>

</selector>
```

**If you can please help I have been stuck on this issue for a really long time and made more posts then I need to, but I just can't seem to solve it. Also I cannot access my logs as I am having technical issues which basically freeze my android studio when I try to click android monitor and my app is running.**

**If all this isn't enough I also posted on github**

https://github.com/BeniReydman/Slide_Menu-Slide_Menu

I will try to solve as much questions as you may have, but I am new and this is my first App. I haven't even been doing this for over a week so please bear with it.

Answer (score 1):

> What happens here is that these buttons are actually in my
>   menu2_layout.xml which is my second fragment but my rootview allows me
>   to find it.

I would usually say post the error but this has thrown me,

rootview is menu1_layou.xml, the buttons are in menu2_layout.xml. 
So you need to call findViewById() on the View that contains the ID's you are looking for.

Yes the code will compile and your IDE will not throw any errors but that doesn't mean it will work.

If you are still having problems after you resolve this then please post the crash logs.

Comment: my rootview was actually created on MyActivity.java, but I did only set rootview to = my menu1_layout at the beginning which I should actually change

Comment: rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu1_layout, container, false);

Comment: is there a way to set rootview to more then 1? Edit* is there a way to return more then 1 rootview.

Comment: You mean inflate multiple layouts into the one object? I don't believe so, I don't see why you should ever need too. You can inflate another layout and attach it to an existing view, but I don't think you need to do that either.

Is there any reason why your four buttons are on another layout if they are used in the menu1 layout?

Comment: In my first layout is where everything takes place. When the user recieves enough cookies (currency in my game) it will change the buttons in the second layout which is the upgrades.

Comment: Basically I want my first fragment to change the look of my second fragment everytime the user recieves currency in my first fragment.

Comment: Okay in that case I would advise not trying to directly change the buttons, but rather create a global variable(s) that each fragment can access and simply have the menu2 fragment check what state the buttons are to be in when it is accessed.

Comment: Is there a way to run a function in fragment 2 everytime the user recieves currency in fragment 1. Because even with a global variable it wouldn't change everytime something happens in fragment 1.